# How to sort points from top to bottom and left to right simoultaneusly

Tags: algorithm, sorting, columnsorting

Given the following image with two axis I need to sort these points in the following order: a, c, e, b, d

[image: XY axis]

If it helps with something, these are rectangles and I also have the bottom right corner of the rectangle.

I've been trying to sort them in `Kotlin` ascending with the `X` and then ascending with the `Y` but it's not what I need.

Comment: What is the specification of the sorting you are looking for? Why should d be after b but c before b?

Comment: The points represent words inside a table, I want to read the information in columns, from top to bottom @pasthec

Comment: but then the column of d is before the column of b, so I don't see what's the problem with a, c, e, d, b?